# Button to close the alert does not work within the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how I am using the Bootstrap Component "Alerts" in a dropdown that will be populated with alerts from my data basse. My alert as such should show the text and the hooping should have an "X" to close the alert. It works outside the dropdown but inside the dropdown does nothing. Can you help me? try to do it manually by js but I don't detect the alert function in : $('.alert').alert('close')

```
<li class="dropdown">
                 <a runat="server" id="lista" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- 
                 toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" 
                 style="color:blanchedalmond" ></span></a>
                 <div id="notificationContainer">

                <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">     
                     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                 <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive 
                action.
                </div>
                </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: You are missing the beginning `ul` tag and an ending `div` tag.

Comment: If I copy the code wrong but if they are in the main code and it does not show me an error